Maven clean not cleaning all directories
Problem: I want to remove /node and /node_modules on clean, but only /node_modules is removed, why?
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/form-src/node</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**</include>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/form-src/node_modules</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**</include>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



This question is similar to: Same plugin with different configurations. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Configurations overwrite each other. Merge into one with multiple file sets

you can merge maven plugin configuration, try this:
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
<configuration>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/form-src/node</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
        </fileset>
        <fileset>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/form-src/node_modules</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</configuration>


Appreciated, thanks
